# How to build and display Consent Pane PLAID with PHP

Tags: javascript, html, plaid

i want to integrate PLAID system on my project based Laravel framework. Currently i'm developing on step to display Consent Pane PLAID from this doc [PLAID LINK DOC](https://plaid.com/docs/link/). I'm using the javascript code. but i still failed to integrate it. here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" /> 
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Plaid</title> 
  <script src="https://cdn.plaid.com/link/v2/stable/link-initialize.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body > 

    plaid
 </body>

 <script>
    const handler = Plaid.create({
        token: 'link-sandbox-xxx',
        onSuccess: (public_token, metadata) => { 
            console.debug("onSuccess"); 
            console.log('public_token: ' + public_token);
            console.log('account ID: ' + metadata.account_id);
        },
        onLoad: () => {
            console.debug("onLoad");
        },
        onExit: (err, metadata) => {
            console.debug("onExit");
            console.log('metadata ' + metadata);
        },
        onEvent: (eventName, metadata) => {
            console.debug("onEvent");
        },
        receivedRedirectUri: "https://domainname.com/plaid",
    });
    handler.open();
   
 </script>
  
</html>
```

Display error

```
POST https://sandbox.plaid.com/link/workflow/start 400 (Bad Request)
Error: oauth uri does not contain a valid oauth_state_id query parameter.
```

i already added new URL my API menu on PLAID Dashboard but still display this error.

Please help. How do i able to integrate that on my laravel?

Comment: Since your question isn't about Laravel or PHP, I removed those tags and added JavaScript. If the question _is_ about Laravel/PHP, then you need to add that code and explain the issue with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `receivedRedirectUri` should not be set when initializing Link for the first time. It is used when initializing Link for the second time, after returning from the OAuth redirect.

Comment: OMG!!! it works after i remove it. thank you @Alex !!